# How to use sscanf to retrieve a string containing space

Tags: c, scanf

```
char s[]="question:Does it have eyes?"
```

I want to retrieve two strings separated by ':'.

```
char question[10];
char content[100];
sscanf(s,"%[a-z]%[a-z]",question,content);
```

As sscanf() retrieves strings by space, I could not get a complete question. How could I retrieve the whole question completely with sscanf()? Thanks.

Comment: Use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code is already almost what you want.  Note in particular that

> sscanf() retrieves strings by space

is not exactly correct.  `sscanf()` interprets whitespace (including more than just the space character) as a field delimiter *for the `%s` field descriptor*, but you can also scan a string via the `%[]` field descriptor, as you already are doing, and that scans whichever characters you tell it to scan.

Additionally, you need to tell `scanf()` to expect the colon, even though it won't be scanned into either of your strings.  Thus, you could solve the problem like so:

```
sscanf(s, "%9[^:]:%99[^\001]", question, content);
```

The first field descriptor scans up to 9 characters plus a string terminator into `question`, accepting any character other than `:`.  It then scans and otherwise ignores a `:`, and scans up to 99 characters different from `'\001'` into `content`.  The `'\001'` is an arbitrary choice among characters that I presume are not expected in the input.

On the other hand, if you expect the string you are scanning always to start with the literal characters `"question:"`, then you might be better off with

```
sscanf(s, "question:%99[^\001]", content);
```

Do remember that `sscanf()`'s return value tells you how many input fields were successfully scanned, which can inform you about parse errors (such as the data not beginning with `"question:"`).

On the third hand, if you expect the string you are scanning to always start with the literal characters `"question:"`, and you just want to capture everything following, then `sscanf()` is a bit of a heavyweight tool for the job.  I'd do it like so, instead:

```
if (!strncmp(s, "question:", 9)) {
    strncpy(content, s + 9, sizeof(content) - 1);
    content[sizeof(content) - 1] = '\0';  /* in case the content was too long */
} else {
    /* handle malformed string */
}
```

Comment: this delimiter `%99[^\001]` is unlikely to stop inputting char until a 0x01 is encountered or 99 characters are input.  A better parameter would be: `%99[^\0]` or perhaps even `%99[^?]` which would not input the '?'

Comment: @user3629249 `"%99[^\0]"` does not work as `*scanf()` will stop using the format once `'\0'` is encountered.  It acts like `"%99[^"`.

Comment: @chux,  Naturally, that '\0' is the last character in the string `s[]` so it will stop inputting characters at exactly the right place.  Then the `sscanf()` will append a '\0', resulting in a valid string in `content[]` that contains the sub string after the `:` in the `s[]` array.

Comment: @user3629249 the _format_ to `scanf()` ends with the embedded null character.  Not talking about `s[]`, just the format to `sscanf()`. It will be as if code was `sscanf(s, "question:%99[^", content);` which will not work.  `sscanf()` does not know there is a `"]"` after the null character with format `"%99[^\0]"`.

Comment: @chux,  I see, thanks for the clarification, so this leaves the 'stop at the ?' method as one that will work.  thus do I live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

Inverted scanset and `"%n"`.
Use `char *content;` rather than `char content[100];`

```
char s[]="question:Does it have eyes?"
char question[10];
char *content;

int n = 0;
sscanf(s, "%9[^:]:%n",question, &n);
if (n == 0) Handle_Failure();
content = s+n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an inverted scanset? For example, there are two of them here:

```
char question[10];
char content[100];
sscanf(s,"%[^:]:%[^\n]",question,content);
```

Comment: Use `sscanf(s,"%[^:]:%[^\n]",question,content);` ( add `:` between the two specifiers) to get the comma out from `content`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Nice spot! Thanks :)

Comment: @user3629249 Please find a citation from a standard supporting your theory (for example, ["Reaching the end of the string in sscanf() shall be equivalent to encountering end-of-file for fscanf()"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) is a citation that invalidates your theory).

Comment: @Seb,  Thanks for that clarification,  It is a detail that I was not familiar with.  I'll remove the erroneous comment.

Comment: @user3629249 Is it often that you write so authoritatively on subjects that you don't know about? Perhaps you could try reading, rather than guessing...